# Spring Batch 5 is not autocreating table in H2 database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, h2

I've created a simple Spring Batch application using H2 database and gradle.  Version of Spring Boot is 3.0.4.  There is only one job and only one step that reads from csv file and logs into the console.  I've already set the flag spring.batch.initialize-schema=always which should have happened anyways when using embedded databases.  I've created a rest controller to trigger the start of the job but getting the error below:

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ? [42104-214]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]

Not sure if there's some extra config needed for H2 database for Spring Boot 3.  Below are some code snippets that might be of relevance:

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
```

Config file for Spring Batch:

```
    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobRepository jobRepository,
                             JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
        return new JobBuilder("importUserJob", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(step1)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(JobRepository jobRepository,
                      PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, ItemWriter<Person> writer) {
        return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
                .<Person, Person> chunk(10, transactionManager)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
        log.info("FlatFileItemReader instance");
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
                .name("personItemReader")
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("something.csv"))
                .delimited()
                .names("firstName", "lastName")
                .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
                    setTargetType(Person.class);
                }})
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersonItemProcessor processor() {
        return new PersonItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Person> writer() {
        return items -> {
            for (Person item : items) {
                System.out.println(item.toString());
            }
        };
    }
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.springbatchtest'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Thanks much!

I've tried creating a Spring Batch application using the latest Spring Boot version 3.  I expected the automatic creation of the tables when using embedded databases as detailed here:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-spring-batch-database.

Instead I got an error saying the tables don't exist

Comment: Please try [`spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema) ...the linked documentation/mentioned property is outdated.

Comment: Tried but same result

Comment: Do you have the annotation `@EnableBatchProcessing` in your code? As of Spring Boot 3, it disables Spring Boot's autoconfiguration for Batch. It is this auto-configuration which creates the tables. If you use the annotation, please try removing it.

Comment: hi @Henning this worked but it automatically ran the job on startup without anything triggering it.  Any idea how to stop this from happening?  I wish an external event to be the trigger.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Spring Boot 3, the annotation `@EnableBatchProcessing` will disable Spring Boot's auto-configuration for Batch. It is this auto-configuration that creates the tables. Thus, you need to remove the annotation from your code.

The auto-configuration also starts jobs on start-up of the application. If you want to disable this particular feature, you can set the property `spring.batch.job.enabled` to `false`.

Comment: How to pass custom "dataSourceRef" and  custom "transactionManagerRef" if we remove that annotation? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the following application property:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```